# Sum of one field (column) of data from multiple csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple CSV files like this

"A.csv"

```
day,pid,wscore,lscore,wk,wd,lk,ld
1,"A",1,0,1,0,0,1
4,"A",2,0,1,0,1,1
5,"A",1,1,2,0,0,2
6,"A",1,0,2,1,1,2
...
```

"B.csv"

```
day,pid,wscore,lscore,wk,wd,lk,ld
1,"B",1,0,2,1,1,2
2,"B",2,2,2,1,0,1
4,"B",2,2,2,2,2,1
5,"B",2,1,1,1,1,1
...
```

"C.csv"

```
day,pid,wscore,lscore,wk,wd,lk,ld
2,"C",2,1,2,1,2,2
3,"C",1,2,2,1,2,2
5,"C",2,2,2,1,1,1
...
```

I wish to "slip in" the days and the pid together, and then the average of wscore,lscore, wk,wd,lk, and ld together

Example output.csv

```
day,pid,wscore,lscore,wk,wd,lk,ld
1,"A,B",1,0,1.5,0.5,0.5,1.5
2,"B,C",2,1.5,2, ...
3,"C",1,2,2, ...
4,"A,B",2,1, ...
5,"A,B,C",2.5, ...
...
```

How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to import the files then join the dataframes https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=pd.concat([A,B,C],axis=0)#A=pd.read_csv('A.csv')
```

If you do not need ',' in `pid`

```
 pd.concat([df.groupby(['day'])['pid'].sum(),df.groupby(['day']).mean()],axis=1)
Out[297]: 
     pid    wscore    lscore        wk        wd        lk        ld
day                                                                 
1     AB  1.000000  0.000000  1.500000  0.500000  0.500000  1.500000
2     BC  2.000000  1.500000  2.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.500000
3      C  1.000000  2.000000  2.000000  1.000000  2.000000  2.000000
4     AB  2.000000  1.000000  1.500000  1.000000  1.500000  1.000000
5    ABC  1.666667  1.333333  1.666667  0.666667  0.666667  1.333333
6      A  1.000000  0.000000  2.000000  1.000000  1.000000  2.000000
```

If you need ','

```
pd.concat([df.groupby(['day'])['pid'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ','.join(x)),df.groupby(['day']).mean()],axis=1)

Out[300]: 
       pid    wscore    lscore        wk        wd        lk        ld
day                                                                   
1      A,B  1.000000  0.000000  1.500000  0.500000  0.500000  1.500000
2      B,C  2.000000  1.500000  2.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.500000
3        C  1.000000  2.000000  2.000000  1.000000  2.000000  2.000000
4      A,B  2.000000  1.000000  1.500000  1.000000  1.500000  1.000000
5    A,B,C  1.666667  1.333333  1.666667  0.666667  0.666667  1.333333
6        A  1.000000  0.000000  2.000000  1.000000  1.000000  2.000000
```

Comment: on `df=pd.concat([A,B,C],axis=0)` does A,B,C here define the csv file name or the 'pid' strings?

Comment: I am added a little  description about A,B,C

Comment: I have this code, (http://prntscr.com/fn4ihz) but it gives me the following error in the screenshot, do you have any solution?

Comment: change int to str `df.id.astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. One last thing, if I were to add two more columns on A.csv, B.csv, C.csv supposedly named "win" and the data is TRUE/FALSE on all the rows, "place" and the data is string.. In what ways can I merge the 3 CSV together? I tried using the code above, it won't show both of the new columns in the output.

Comment: Mark the day Id in A,after `pd.concat`, use `merge` with A again. `Key=day`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "mark"? I'm new to coding, forgive my shallow knowledge in coding..

Comment: Just treat it as `key` when you `merge`